# How to extend actionPerformed method when extending a JButton class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, extends

If I have class A which extends JButton and implements ActionListener and it performs a certain default action. Then I have class B which extends class A and I want it to do the same action, plus something else. How do I go about extending the class A's actionPerformed method?

Class A:

```
class AButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    AButton () {
        addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent aEvent) {
        methodA();
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
class BButton extends AButton {
    BButton () {
        super();
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvent) {
               methodB();
           } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to extend JButton, simply create a Action and apply it to the first button, extend the original Action, modify its behavior as you need and apply it to the second button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override methodA() rather than actionPerformed() call

```
protected void methodA() {
  super.methodA();
  //additional actions here
}
```

Comment: This answer worked best and simpliest for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to do the same action, plus something else.

You can add multiple `ActionListener` on same `JButton` and all will fired when button is clicked but make sure the order of the listeners are not predefined and should not be.

Never extend any build-in class until and unless you need to override existing functionality.

Read more about [Favor Composition over inheritance Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

---

If you want to do in the same way then try some thing like this:

```
class AButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    AButton () {
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent aEvent) {
        methodA();
        methodB();
    }

    public void methodB(){
        // nothing here, no code
        // you can make this method abstract if needed
    }
}

class BButton extends AButton {

    @Override
    public void methodB(){
        // add more code here specific to this class
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to not create custom swing components by etending them, but to create instances of them and then add functionality?

Comment: Let me provide you some solution with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. You cannot inherit an anonymous class. You should write an action handler implementing ActionListener, and then extend from this handler for your second class.